# How to plot green and red dots or labels when QQE fast curve crosses slow curve and vice-versa

Tags: charts, label, pine-script

I'm working further on a pine script for TradingView originally developed by Glaz Metastock Version of QQE (published Feb 19, 2015).

I've been able to modify it a bit however I want to be able to plot 'red' and 'green' dots and/or labels when the Fast and Slow curves intersect each other.

If fast green curve goes **above** slow red curve then display *green/long signal* as a dot or label. If fast green curve goes **below** slow red red curve then display *red/short signal* as dot or label.

I've attempted to incorporate the QQE Crosses, Conditions and Plotting written by another user QQE signals by colinmck.

However when I combine the code, I get an error that script can't be compiled:

```
Script could not be translated from: |B|QQExlong := nz(QQExlong[1]
Script 'QQE by glaz_ba copy' has been saved
```

Below is the script I've written as it stands:

```
study("QQE ba copy")
src=close
Fast=input(2.6180)
Slow=input(4.2360)
RSI=input(13)
SF=input(5,title='Slow Factor')
WiMA(src, length) => 
    MA_s=(src + nz(MA_s[1] * (length-1)))/length
    MA_s

RSIndex= ema(rsi(close,RSI), SF)

//{Smoothed ATR of Smoothed RSI}
TH= iff(RSIndex[1] > RSIndex, RSIndex[1], RSIndex)
TL= iff(RSIndex[1] < RSIndex, RSIndex[1], RSIndex)
TR= TH-TL

AtrRsi= WiMA(TR, 14)
SmoothedAtrRsi= WiMA(AtrRsi, 14)

//{Fast and Slow ATR Trailing Levels} 
// Fast
DeltaFastAtrRsi= SmoothedAtrRsi*Fast
newshortband_f=  RSIndex + DeltaFastAtrRsi
newlongband_f= RSIndex - DeltaFastAtrRsi
longband_f=RSIndex[1] > longband_f[1] and RSIndex > longband_f[1] ? max(longband_f[1],newlongband_f):newlongband_f
shortband_f=RSIndex[1] < shortband_f[1] and  RSIndex < shortband_f[1] ? min(shortband_f[1], newshortband_f):newshortband_f
trend_f=cross(RSIndex, shortband_f[1])?1:cross(longband_f[1], RSIndex)?-1:nz(trend_f[1],1)
FastAtrRsiTL = trend_f==1? longband_f: shortband_f

// Slow
DeltaSlowAtrRsi= SmoothedAtrRsi*Slow
newshortband_s=  RSIndex + DeltaSlowAtrRsi
newlongband_s= RSIndex - DeltaSlowAtrRsi
longband_s=RSIndex[1] > longband_s[1] and RSIndex > longband_s[1] ? max(longband_s[1],newlongband_s):newlongband_s
shortband_s=RSIndex[1] < shortband_s[1] and  RSIndex < shortband_s[1] ? min(shortband_s[1], newshortband_s):newshortband_s
trend_s=cross(RSIndex, shortband_s[1])?1:cross(longband_s[1], RSIndex)?-1:nz(trend_s[1],1)
SlowAtrRsiTL= trend_s==1? longband_s: shortband_s

// Find all the QQE Crosses
QQExlong = 0
QQExlong := nz(QQExlong[1])
QQExshort = 1
QQExshort := nz(QQExshort[1])
QQExlong := FastAtrRsiTL < RSIndex ? QQExlong + 1 : 0
QQExshort := FastAtrRsiTL > RSIndex ? QQExshort + 1 : 0
//

//Conditions
qqeLong = QQExlong == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[1] - 50 : na
qqeShort = QQExshort == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[1] - 50 : na
//

// Plotting
plotshape(qqeLong, title="QQE long", text="L", textcolor=white, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
plotshape(qqeShort, title="QQE short", text="S", textcolor=white, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=red, transp=0, size=size.tiny)
//

plot(RSIndex,title="RSIndex",color=#7E57C2)
plot(FastAtrRsiTL,title="FastAtrRSI",color=green)
plot(SlowAtrRsiTL,title="SlowAtrRSI",color=red)

band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#D3D3D3)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=#787B86)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#D3D3D3)
fill(band1, band0, color=#F5F5F5, title="Background")
```

I've attached a sample image on what ideally results would look like:

[Output screenshot on bottom QQE plot w/ labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O67rU.jpg)

Please help on solution for this!

Answer (score 0):

This script revised unto pine-script version 5 seems to fix the issue from earlier!

However it does create a weird condition where labels are not plotting correctly relative to location :S

```
//@version=5
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © colinmck - currently edited by ba17 on 1/3/21

indicator("RSI + QQE signals_ba")

RSI_Period = input(14, title='RSI Length')
SF = input(5, title='RSI Smoothing Factor')
QQEFast = input(4.238, title='Fast QQE Factor')
QQESlow = input(2.618, title='Slow QQE Factor')
// ThreshHold = input(10, title="ThresHold")

src = close
Wilders_Period = RSI_Period * 2 - 1

Rsi = ta.rsi(src, RSI_Period)
RsiMa = ta.ema(Rsi, SF)
AtrRsi = math.abs(RsiMa[1] - RsiMa)
MaAtrRsi = ta.ema(AtrRsi, Wilders_Period)
dar_f = ta.ema(MaAtrRsi, Wilders_Period) * QQEFast
dar_s = ta.ema(MaAtrRsi, Wilders_Period) * QQESlow

longband_f = 0.0, longband_s = 0.0
shortband_f = 0.0, shortband_s= 0.0
trend_f = 0, trend_s = 0

// Fast ATR Trailing Levels
DeltaFastAtrRsi = dar_f
RSIndex = RsiMa
newshortband_f = RSIndex + DeltaFastAtrRsi
newlongband_f = RSIndex - DeltaFastAtrRsi
longband_f := RSIndex[1] > longband_f[1] and RSIndex > longband_f[1] ? math.max(longband_f[1], newlongband_f) : newlongband_f
shortband_f := RSIndex[1] < shortband_f[1] and RSIndex < shortband_f[1] ? math.min(shortband_f[1], newshortband_f) : newshortband_f
cross_f = ta.cross(longband_f[1], RSIndex)
trend_f := ta.cross(RSIndex, shortband_f[1]) ? 1 : cross_f ? -1 : nz(trend_f[1], 1)
FastAtrRsiTL = trend_f == 1 ? longband_f : shortband_f

// Slow Fast ATR Trailing Levels
DeltaSlowAtrRsi = dar_s
// RSIndex = RsiMa
newshortband_s = RSIndex + DeltaSlowAtrRsi
newlongband_s = RSIndex - DeltaSlowAtrRsi
longband_s := RSIndex[1] > longband_s[1] and RSIndex > longband_s[1] ? math.max(longband_s[1], newlongband_s) : newlongband_s
shortband_s := RSIndex[1] < shortband_s[1] and RSIndex < shortband_s[1] ? math.min(shortband_s[1], newshortband_s) : newshortband_s
cross_s = ta.cross(longband_s[1], RSIndex)
trend_s := ta.cross(RSIndex, shortband_s[1]) ? 1 : cross_s ? -1 : nz(trend_s[1], 1)
SlowAtrRsiTL = trend_s == 1 ? longband_s : shortband_s

// Find all the QQE Crosses

QQExlong = 0
QQExlong := nz(QQExlong[1])
QQExshort = 0
QQExshort := nz(QQExshort[1])
QQExlong := FastAtrRsiTL < RSIndex ? QQExlong + 1 : 0
QQExshort := FastAtrRsiTL > RSIndex ? QQExshort + 1 : 0

//Conditions

qqeLong = QQExlong == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[1] - 50 : na
qqeShort = QQExshort == 1 ? FastAtrRsiTL[1] - 50 : na


// Plotting (new ba)
plot(RsiMa,title="RSI MA",color=#7E57C2)
plot(FastAtrRsiTL,title="FastAtrRSI",color=color.green)
plot(SlowAtrRsiTL,title="SlowAtrRSI",color=color.red)

// Plotting (original)

plotshape(qqeLong, title="QQE long", text="L", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.rgb(0,128,0,20), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(qqeShort, title="QQE short", text="S", textcolor=color.white, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.rgb(255,0,0,20), transp=20, size=size.tiny)


band1 = hline(70, "Upper Band", color=#D3D3D3)
bandm = hline(50, "Middle Band", color=#787B86)
band0 = hline(30, "Lower Band", color=#D3D3D3)
```

Labels seem to be placed -50 units in y-dir

Any tips on moving labels to correct position?